# I'm trying to scrape real estate listings from an mls site and have had luck with beautiful soup, maybe selenium would be easier?

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

maybe this or something like it has been answered before and that might be enough to point me in the right direction? The site loads up 24 listings at a time, then it has a see more results button, which loads the next 24, keeping the first 24 there, until you hit 96 listings, then it only keeps 96 total, however everytime I've tried to scrape it with beautiful soup I only get the first 24. Every attempt I've made with selenium has not yielded anything, I plan on looking at those failures with the documentation a little closer tomorrow and possibly adding more to this question or figuring something up, but my gut says beautiful soup is the way to go, or suck it up, copy and paste 96 at a time and deal with it with regex and or pandas (shoulder shrug emoji)

I'm trying to scrape mls listings, and have had some luck, the page loads 24 at a time, and it keeps the previous listings up for a while, using beautiful soup I can extract sales price by pulling this from the outer html

```
url = """https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?k=990316X949Z&p=DE-77667588-490"""
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
# this extracts sale price
soup.find_all("span", {"class":"d-fontSize--largest"})
# returns the following: <span class="d-fontSize--largest">$50,000</span>
```

next I've extracted address as follows

```
soup.find_all("div", {"class":"col-sm-12 d-fontSize--largest d-text d-color--brandDark"})
# this returns: 
<div class="col-sm-12 d-fontSize--largest d-text d-color--brandDark">
 <span class="formula J_formula"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|4526,,0')">403 W  Main Street</a></span></div>
```

next I get town, state and zip code from the following outer html

```
soup.find_all("div", {"class":"col-sm-12 d-fontSize--small d-textSoft d-paddingBottom--8"})
# which returns a list of these
<div class="col-sm-12 d-fontSize--small d-textSoft d-paddingBottom--8">
 <span class="formula J_formula"> Cleveland, MO 64734</span></div>
```

Next I might use some help here, but I think i see enough of a pattern to get it on my own

```
soup.find_all("span", {"class":"d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5"})
#this returns the following
[<span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">3</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">1</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">1</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">1,307</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">Single Family</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">2</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">1</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">0</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">960</span>,
 <span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">Single Family</span>,
# which looks to have the format
#bedrooms
#bathrooms
#half baths
#square footage
#residence type
```

which now leads to my question, at the bottom of the page is a "see more results" button
here is the outer html and the full html for it:

```
#outer
<a role="button" class="btn mtx-btn-brandAlt" id="_ctl0_m_DisplayCore_dpy121" href="javascript:PortalResultsJs.getNextDisplaySet();">See More Results</a>
#full
<!--Paging Next link-->
<div id="_ctl0_m_divPagedListingsNext" class="mtx-pageMore j-resultsPageNext hidden-print" style="display: block;"><a role="button" class="btn mtx-btn-brandAlt" id="_ctl0_m_DisplayCore_dpy121" href="javascript:PortalResultsJs.getNextDisplaySet();">See More Results</a></div>
```

when I click it simply brings in the next 24 results and does not take me to a new page so I do not know what I would do to scrape this?

there might be a better way to scrape this so here is the html for an entire listing

```
<div class=" col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

<span class="d-fontSize--largest">$90,000</span><span class="d-paddingLeft--6 d-paddingBottom--2"></span></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 d-textAlign--right col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<span class="formula J_formula"><div class="dropdown mtx-dropdownModal mtx-bucketSelector j-portalBucketSelector" data-key="51065729" data-currentbucket="0"><a href="#" title="Save as Favorite" onclick="Dpy.changeDropDownPosition( this );" class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon-bucketNone j-portalBucketSelectorIcon" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;"></a><ul class="dropdown-menu is-bucketNone mtx-bucketSelector-menu j-portalBucketSelector-menu"><li class="mtx-bucket--favoriteRemove"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;6&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketFavoriteRemove"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Remove from Favorites</span></a></li><li class="mtx-bucket--possibilitiesRemove"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;4&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketPossibilitiesRemove"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Remove from Possibilities</span></a></li><li class="mtx-bucket--discardsRemove"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketDiscardsRemove"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Remove from Discards</span></a></li><li class="mtx-bucket--favorite"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;6&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketFavorite"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Save as Favorite</span></a></li><li class="mtx-bucket--possibilities"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;4&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketPossibilities"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Save as Possibility</span></a></li><li class="mtx-bucket--discards"><a href="#" onclick="Dpy.clickPortalBucketResponsive(&quot;51065729&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,event);"><span class="mtx-btn-link mtx-icon mtx-icon--small mtx-icon-bucketDiscards"></span><span class="mtx-textSoft" style="vertical-align:middle;">Discard Listing</span></a></li></ul></div></span>
</div>
<div class=" col-xs-9 d-fontSize--small col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">

<span class="formula J_formula"><span class="Status_SOLD">Sold</span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-sm-12 d-fontSize--largest d-text d-color--brandDark">

<span class="formula J_formula"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|4526,,9')">1324 W  Campbell Boulevard</a></span></div>
<div class=" col-sm-12 d-fontSize--small d-textSoft d-paddingBottom--8">

<span class="formula J_formula"> Raymore, MO 64083</span></div>
<div class=" col-sm-12">

</div>
<div class=" col-sm-12">

<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">2</span><span class="d-text d-fieldsSeparatorComma">Bedrms</span><span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">2</span><span class="d-text d-fieldsSeparatorComma">Full Bath(s)</span><span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">0</span><span class="d-text d-fieldsSeparatorComma">Half Bath(s)</span><span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">1,386</span><span class="d-text d-fieldsSeparatorComma">Sqft</span><span class="d-text  d-paddingRight--5">Built in</span><span class="d-textStrong d-fieldsSeparatorComma">1980</span><span class="d-textStrong d-paddingRight--5">Patio/Villa</span></div></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div></div>
<div class=" col-sm-12">

</div><div class=" col-sm-12">

</div><div class=" col-sm-12">

</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 hidden-sm d-paddingTop--4 d-paddingBottom--4 hidden-md hidden-xs">

<span class="d-textSoft">Experience maintenance free living  in this premier retirement communitie!  Enjoy numerous amenities...</span></div><div class=" col-sm-12">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "see more results" button, an API call is triggered and the result is rendered in the same page.

When you check the call it is :

```
POST https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/matrix/public/getdisplay/ByKeys.ashx
```

with some form data including a cross forgery token named `did`, you can find this value in the cookie named `Display`. Also, you have a parameter named `keys` which includes the id of all real estate items you want to query. It seems the complete list is present in the page if you look at `input` tag with `id: _ctl0_m_hfKeys`

This way, you can requests all the results (at the present time 391) in one single request.

The following extract all items and append them into an array :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get("https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?k=990316X949Z&p=DE-77667588-490")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

keys = soup.find("input",{"id":"_ctl0_m_hfKeys"})["value"]
did = session.cookies.get_dict()["Display"]

r = requests.post("https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/matrix/public/getdisplay/ByKeys.ashx",
  params = {
    "drm": "email"
  },
  data = {
    "keys": keys,
    "did": did,
    "tid": 1,
    "l": 1,
    "pbs": 1
   })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

items = []

for i in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"multiLineDisplay"}):
  span = i.find_all("span")
  item = {
    "image": span[0].find("img")["src"],
    "price": span[1].text,
    "status1": span[4].text,
    "status2": span[5].text,
    "address1": span[6].text,
    "address2": span[7].text,
    "bedroomNum": span[8].text,
    "FullBathroomNum": span[10].text,
    "HalfBathroomNum": span[12].text,
    "sqft": span[14].text,
  }
  if (len(span)>20):
    item["builtIn"] = span[17].text
    item["acres"] = span[18].text
    item["family"] = span[20].text
    item["description"] = span[21].text
  elif (len(span)>19):
    item["builtIn"] = span[17].text
    item["family"] = span[18].text
    item["description"] = span[19].text
  else:
    item["family"] = span[15].text
    item["description"] = span[16].text
  items.append(item)

print(pprint.pprint(items))
print(len(items))
```

Comment: thank you! huge help, I'd just gotten to the requests.post but this saves me a tremendous amount of time